# Ember - Route event for attempting transition to active route

Tags: events, ember.js, transition, ember-router

I'm trying to make sure my side menu closes anytime someone attempts to transition to any route, even the same route the user is already on.

This doesn't fire on the attempt to the same route, just on all others:

```
var ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        willTransition: function(){
            // Close menu always
            //this.controllerFor('application').set('menuOpen', false);     
            console.log('willTransition fired!');
        }
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You could try `beforeModel`

Comment: Why not set `menuOpen` to false on link click ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you get any hooks when transitioning to self. A possible workaround is to fire an action on link click and handle transitioning inside the action instead of using `link-to`

Something like the following:

`<a href='#' {{action 'route1'}}>ROUTE 1</a>`

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    route1: function(){
      console.log("DO SOMETHING HERE");

      this.transitionToRoute('one');
    }
  }
});
```

Check out [this jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/marewamume/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: I'd then have to do this for all links on my site, it would be so much code. But there is some event getting fired, because the LOG shows a "Attempting URL transition to <ROUTE>", so behind the scenes Ember does have an event firing to trigger that LOG right?

Comment: True. Except that when I downloaded the emberjs source code - I cannot find "Attempting transition to" anywhere... strange...